# Можно ли установить текст на ImageButton?

Tags: android, java

Можно ли как-то установить текст на ImageButton или анимировать обычный Button?
В общем мне нужно решить проблему: должна быть кнопка с анимацией нажатия(или что-либо, что кликается), и поверх нее текст. Как это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Лайауты всегда нужно стараться писать оптимально. Приведенный пример валидный, но он состоит из 3-х компонентов.
Насколько я понял из вопроса то можно обойтись более простым лайаутом

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/appmenu_btn_style"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_appmenu_photos"
    android:drawablePadding="15dp"
    android:onClick="dispatchAppMenuClick"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="18dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:tag="photos_btn"
    android:text="@string/appmenu_photos"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="9pt" />
```

благодаря android:clickable="true" приведенный TextView "прикидывается" кнопкой. Далее достаточно только прописать состояния для нашей "кнопки" и дело в шляпе.
Файл res/drawable/appmenu_btn_style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/appmenu_btn_pressed" />
</selector>
```

Файл res/drawable/appmenu_btn_pressed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#737373" />
</shape>
```

В простых лайаутах задумываться над оптимизацией view-ов может и не имеет особого смысла, а вот когда нужно отлейаутить элемент списка -- то крайне желательно уделять внимание "оптимальности"

Answer (score 4):

Можно поверх `ImageButton` расположить `TextView` - надо просто использовать `FrameLayout`, типа:

```
<FrameLayout>
     <ImageButton android:background="@null" 
                  android:id="@+id/myButton" 
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:src="@drawable/myButton"/> 
     <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
               android:text="Мой текст"/>
</FrameLayout>
```