# Вставить рисунок в TextView

Tags: android

Я заполняю TextView из ресурсов, есть необходимость в текст вставить рисунок, существует ли такая возможность?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в TextView есть текст, то в данном примере рисунок будет слева (собственно, текст справа):

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
Drawable img = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
img.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);
textView.setCompoundDrawables(img, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если заранее известно какой рисунок нужно вставить в TextView то лучше это сделать непосредственно в файле layout'а. Как пример можно посмотреть [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/73556#73604)